# DenoiseImage in ANTS tool, raising an error related to ITKv5

Tags: itk, simpleitk

Once I am trying to run `DenoiseImage` in [ANTS tool](http://stnava.github.io/ANTs/),

```
DenoiseImage -d 3 -i image-001.nii -o noise-image-001.nii --verbose 1
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Running for 3-dimensional images.

Exception caught: 
itk::ExceptionObject (0x192cd00)
Location: "unknown" 
File: /home/es/softwares/code/antsbin/ITKv5/Modules/Core/Common/src/itkPoolMultiThreader.cxx
Line: 202
Description: itk::ERROR: PoolMultiThreader(0x5f85040): Exception occurred during SingleMethodExecute
/home/es/softwares/code/antsbin/ITKv5-install/include/ITK-5.0/itkImageSource.hxx:280:
itk::ERROR: VarianceImageFilter(0x4811510): Subclass should override this method!!! If old behavior is desired invoke this->DynamicMultiThreadingOff(); before Update() is called. The best place is in class constructor.
```

Could you please help if you know any solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ITKv5 has not been officially released yet, and migrating from v4 to v5 involves some code changes or additional compatibility flags to be set. ANTS appears not to support ITKV5 yet.

Some information about the changes can be found in the ITKv5 alpha 2 release notes:
https://discourse.itk.org/t/itk-5-0-alpha-2-performance/959

Comment: Thanks for your reply, How to force ANTs to install ITKv4? I mean `ITK_VERSION_MAJOR` is 5 and I am not able to edit the version number.